# Why would sort fail?

Tags: php, sorting

I'm writing a library routine, which among other things will do some rather complex sorting of nested arrays.

I see from the documentation that all the array sort function (including the ones using built-in comparators) can return false on failure - but when would this ever be the case???

Comment: This needs to be added to the documentation.  Has anyone already submitted a bug report for that?  https://bugs.php.net/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It would fail when the variable you send to the function is **NOT** an array
Example:

```
asort('Hello');//fails
asort(array(1,2,35,7,2,8,3));//true
```

Comment: This should be handled as an exception, not a return-type.

Comment: @raveline - perhaps that's how it should work, but it doesn't work like that. It does work exactly as maniator has said.

Comment: @Raveline: I believe that basic PHP functions don't throw Exceptions unless you throw them yourself in an error handler (that you'd have to write first).

Comment: @Raveline It's for historical reasons and compatibility with old code. New fonctions added to php will use exceptions but not the old ones...

Comment: @Mark Baker and @Nils Werner : You're absolutely right. This is why a) my comment was a comment b) I used the modal "should".

Comment: Must admit to being surprised by that - like Ravline I'd have expected an exception. Actually on my machine I get a fatal error trying to call a function with a literal when it requires a reference - but using a scalar variable, it does indeed return false.

Comment: Can anyone positively verify that this is the **ONLY** condition for which `sort()` (etc) returns FALSE?  Otherwise, this answer might well be misleading!

Comment: ...Actually it isn't the only condition:  For example if some of the items to be sorted are themselves arrays, it fails. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14707486/999120

Comment: @Doin actually that's wrong - there was an other error in the linked question (the author used the return type), but you are right with there are other conditions. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/51371032/1043150

Comment: Well just to clarify for lazy readers who don't want to follow that link, it explains that there are NO arrays that `sort()` can't sort.  `false` is returned only if the first argument is not an array, the 2nd (optional) argument if present is not an int, or if there are more than 2 arguments.  So in other words if you call the function as the manual prescribes, it will never return `false`.

Answer (score 3):

I also stumbled upon this question and did some research, if there are other conditions, when sort returns false. A look into the code showed [this sort](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/3588d8af129489eda3e3fdb9612b09a4da16dcfd/ext/standard/array.c#L921) function

```
PHP_FUNCTION(sort)
{
    zval *array;
    zend_long sort_type = PHP_SORT_REGULAR;
    compare_func_t cmp;

    ZEND_PARSE_PARAMETERS_START(1, 2)
        Z_PARAM_ARRAY_EX(array, 0, 1)
        Z_PARAM_OPTIONAL
        Z_PARAM_LONG(sort_type)
    ZEND_PARSE_PARAMETERS_END_EX(RETURN_FALSE);

    cmp = php_get_data_compare_func(sort_type, 0);

    if (zend_hash_sort(Z_ARRVAL_P(array), cmp, 1) == FAILURE) {
        RETURN_FALSE;
    }
    RETURN_TRUE;
}
```

On the first view, you see, that the sort function only returns `false`, if `zend_hash_sort` fails. `zend_hash_sort` is a macro, which actually calls `zend_hash_sort_ex`. This function was build pretty robust and returns SUCCESS in [all cases](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/3588d8af129489eda3e3fdb9612b09a4da16dcfd/Zend/zend_hash.c#L2391) - even if you pass arrays with totally uncompareable elements.

This leads us back to the sort function, which does some parameter checking with macros and has three rules.

1. The function takes at least one argument and max 2 arguments.
2. The first argument must be an array
3. The second argument (if given) must be an long

So `sort` returns only `false` in case, one of this three rules is broken.

```
$a = false;
sort($a); // fails because of rule 2
$a = [];
sort($a, "test"); // failes because of rule 3
sort($a, 0, "test"); // failes because of rule 1
```

Answer (score 2):

When the parameter supplied is not an array (or maybe even just an empty array).

Answer (score -1):

Examples of a return of false could include an empty array, variable not an array, insufficient memory available, library call fail, runtime fail of the sorting module, call parameters not valid, disk pack or drive not online, sorting algorithm or method not compatible with rules of the region or country of development.

Comment: Sorry "developer" but there's so much about this answer that's just plain wrong.

Comment: @developer:  If you want to helpfully answer this question, you have to positively identify which of these types of "general sort failure conditions" the PHP `sort()` function *does actually return FALSE for*.  From the accepted answer, that would be solely "variable not an array".  If the others occurred, they would likely cause runtime errors, not a FALSE return value.

Comment: +1'd this.  Until there's an ISO specification saying otherwise, the function can return false for any reason at all.  Even if the implementation designer feels like it for no apparent reason.  It would be ridiculous, but there's no hard guarantee made anywhere.