# I try to sort an array using sort() but it fails

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

```
 if ( $_GET['_value'] == 'moto'  )
     {
        $array[] = array('1' => 'Yamaha');
        $array[] = array('2' => 'Suzuki');  
        $array[] = array('3' => 'Triumph');
        $array[] = array('4' => 'KTM');
        $array[] = array('5' => 'Honda');
        $array[] = array('6' => 'Harley Davidson');
        $array[] = array('7' => 'Buell');
        $array[] = array('8' => 'MV Agusta');
        $array[] = array('9' => 'Ducati');
        $array[] = array('10' => 'Other');

      } 
 $array = sort($array);
 echo json_encode( $array );
```

that is the code i have and its pulled by a chained dropdown. 
I want it to return the values sorted alphabetically but based on the code you see it returns an empty array. what could be the mistake I am making /

Comment: Why are you assigning keys? It will remove any existing keys that may have been assigned, rather than just reordering the keys. So, if you remove the keys, then $array will be simple array and not 2D. Then try sort function.

Comment: yeah that was dumb from my part thank you

Comment: sort($array) sorts the array as passed by reference; the return value is a success/fail boolean that you're then assigning to your freshly sorted array, overwriting that array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not at all pretty but this does the job.

Unless you're constrained otherwise you should really use some of the other suggestions.

```
<?
if ( $_GET['_value'] == 'moto'  ) {
    $array[] = array('1' => 'Yamaha');
    $array[] = array('2' => 'Suzuki');  
    $array[] = array('3' => 'Triumph');
    $array[] = array('4' => 'KTM');
    $array[] = array('5' => 'Honda');
    $array[] = array('6' => 'Harley Davidson');
    $array[] = array('7' => 'Buell');
    $array[] = array('8' => 'MV Agusta');
    $array[] = array('9' => 'Ducati');
    $array[] = array('10' => 'Other');
    foreach($array as $i => $v)
    {
        $v = array_values($v);
        $sort[] = $v[0];
    }
    sort($sort);
    $c = 0;
    foreach($sort as $i => $v)
    {
        $c++;
        $sorted[] = array($c=>$v);
    }

    echo json_encode($sorted);
}
?>
```

Comment: uasort() solution is shorter!

Answer (score 4):

Your code fails because you have an array of arrays here.
You should either search for "sort php array by sub-array key"
Or you can try something like:

```
$array[1] = 'Yamaha';
$array[2] = 'Suzuki'; 
// ...
sort($array);
echo json_encode($array);
```

Comment: It is not necessary (or even pointless) to assign the result of `sort($array)` to `$array`. The function `sort()` works by reference on the argument `$array` http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php. It would be better to just have `sort($array); echo json_encode( $array );`

Answer (score 3):

Your array contains arrays, hence cannot be sorted, try:

```
$array[1] = 'Yamaha';       

$array[2] = 'Suzuki';
```

then `sort($array)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use uasort() function

like:

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    $a = reset($a);
    $b = reset($b);
    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}

uasort($array, 'cmp')
```

Comment: it is worth noting that the OP should also remove those `array(array())` parts and then json encode anyway. If keys need to be preserved, then make a map beforehand.

Comment: You can't now how JSON is treated in the other side, so it is straight forward answer to the question.